# How to replace placeholders in python strings

Tags: python, string

If I have a string like this in Python, how can I fill the placeholders?

```
s = """
uri1: %s/file1.txt
md5: %s
uri2: %s/file2.txt
md5: %s
uri3: %s/file3.txt
md5: %s
"""
```

The `uri` will remain same, however, `md5` will change. So for the above, the final output would be something like this:

```
uri1: file:///somepath/foo/file1.txt
md5: 1234
uri2: file:///somepath/foo/file2.txt
md5: 4321
uri3: file:///somepath/foo/file3.txt
md5: 9876
```

I know I can fill every `%s` but what if I don't want to duplicate the same variable each time? i.e. I want to avoid doing this:

```
s = """
uri1: %s/file1.txt
md5: %s
uri2: %s/file2.txt
md5: %s
uri3: %s/file3.txt
md5: %s
""" % (self.URI, self.md5_for_1, self.URI, self.md5_for_2, self.URI, self.md5_for_3)
```

In the above, I have to specify `self.URI` each time...I'm wondering if there is a way to be able to just specify it once?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check out `str.format`:

```
string = """
uri1: {s.URI}/file1.txt
md5: {s.md5_for_1}
uri2: {s.URI}/file2.txt
md5: {s.md5_for_2}
uri3: {s.URI}/file3.txt
md5: {s.md5_for_3}
""".format(s=self)
```

Here is a page to help. [https://pyformat.info](https://pyformat.info/#getitem_and_getattr)

Answer (score 5):

You can use values more than once, for example:

```
"{0} {0} {1}".format("a", "b")
'a a b'
```

Answer (score 3):

why not use `.format`

```
s = """
uri1: {uri}/file1.txt
md5: {uri}
uri2: {uri}/file2.txt
md5: {uri}
uri3: {uri}/file3.txt
md5: {uri}
""".format(uri=self.URI)
```